# A good way of testing jsx components that used RequireJS define from jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, requirejs, jestjs

I want to test ReactJS component with jest but have a trouble because component using RequireJS define. This is example code (truncated).

```
// component.js

define(function(require){
    var React = require('react');
    // code 
    var _ = require('underscorejs');

    var somename = React.createClass({

        propTypes: {

        },

        getDefaultProps: function () {
            return {

            };
        },

        render: function () {
            // implementation 
        }

    });

    return React.createClass({
        // implementation
    });

});
```

When I tried into test:

```
import ComponentName from '../path/to/ComponentName.jsx';
```

i receive this error:

```
Runtime Error
ReferenceError: define is not defined
```

I was think about to process source with preprocessor. It is possibillity to use scriptPreprocessor option but this is some kind of hacky from my point of view.

I would be very grateful for any ideas and recommendations.